# multiprocessing Pool with decorated function gives me "object has no attribute"

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Below is a reproducible code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def method_exception_catcher(method):

    def method_exception_caught(*args, **kwargs):

        try:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)

        except Exception as e:
            raise type(e)(str(e) + ' from [{}] method'.format(method.__name__)) 

    return method_exception_caught

class MyClass():

    @method_exception_catcher
    def do_something(self, elem):
        return 1/0

    @method_exception_catcher
    def parallel_do_something(self):

        with contextlib.closing(Pool(processes=1)) as p:

            procs = [p.apply_async(self.do_something, args=(3, )) for k in range(1)]
            results = [proc.get() for proc in procs]
            p.close()
            p.join()

        return results

MyClass().parallel_do_something()
```

That code gives me "AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'method_exception_caught'" error.

How can I fix this and have it successfully raise division by 0 error? Thanks!!

UPDATE:

Here is the full error output:

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'method_exception_caught'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: You are right. I added the full message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickling a function just writes down its (module and) **name**; unpickling (imports the module and) looks up the name.  Since your class’s methods (*i.e.*, the functions returned from the decorator) have a `__name__` of `method_exception_caught`, that’s what pickling uses.

The answer (which is a good idea for other reasons as well) is to use `functools.wraps` to make your wrapper functions emulate the wrapped function:

```
def decorator(f):
  @functools.wraps(f)
  def wrap(*a,**kw): return f(*a,**kw)
  return wrap
```